# Unable to read Outlook(.msg) files in R

Tags: r, outlook, text-mining, tm

I have a lot (1400) of outlook emails (.msg format) which I want to process further. R meets most of my text mining needs but for this I'm unable to find any solution. 
I have used readMail from tm.plugin.mail, but haven't been successful

```
 newsgroup <- file.path("D:", "mails")
 news <- VCorpus(DirSource(newsgroup), readerControl = list(reader = readMail))
 inspect(news)
```

Any help/suggestion would be greatly appreciated

Thanks!...

Comment: Adjusted the code formatiing

Comment: What does "haven't been successful" mean exactly? Are you getting error messages? It's hard to help without a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 4):

You can now use [`msgxtractr`](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/msgxtractr) to do this:

```
devtools::install_github("hrbrmstr/msgxtractr")

library(msgxtractr)

print(str(read_msg(system.file("extdata/unicode.msg", package="msgxtractr"))))

## List of 7
##  $ headers         :Classes 'tbl_df', 'tbl' and 'data.frame':    1 obs. of  18 variables:
##   ..$ Return-path               : chr "<brizhou@gmail.com>"
##   ..$ Received                  :List of 1
##   .. ..$ : chr [1:4] "from st11p00mm-smtpin007.mac.com ([17.172.84.240])\nby ms06561.mac.com (Oracle Communications Messaging Server "| __truncated__ "from mail-vc0-f182.google.com ([209.85.220.182])\nby st11p00mm-smtpin007.mac.com\n(Oracle Communications Messag"| __truncated__ "by mail-vc0-f182.google.com with SMTP id ie18so3484487vcb.13 for\n<brianzhou@me.com>; Mon, 18 Nov 2013 00:26:25 -0800 (PST)" "by 10.58.207.196 with HTTP; Mon, 18 Nov 2013 00:26:24 -0800 (PST)"
##   ..$ Original-recipient        : chr "rfc822;brianzhou@me.com"
##   ..$ Received-SPF              : chr "pass (st11p00mm-smtpin006.mac.com: domain of brizhou@gmail.com\ndesignates 209.85.220.182 as permitted sender)\"| __truncated__
##   ..$ DKIM-Signature            : chr "v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;        d=gmail.com;\ns=20120113; h=mime-version:date:message-id:subject:f"| __truncated__
##   ..$ MIME-version              : chr "1.0"
##   ..$ X-Received                : chr "by 10.221.47.193 with SMTP id ut1mr14470624vcb.8.1384763184960;\nMon, 18 Nov 2013 00:26:24 -0800 (PST)"
##   ..$ Date                      : chr "Mon, 18 Nov 2013 10:26:24 +0200"
##   ..$ Message-id                : chr "<CADtJ4eNjQSkGcBtVteCiTF+YFG89+AcHxK3QZ=-Mt48xygkvdQ@mail.gmail.com>"
##   ..$ Subject                   : chr "Test for TIF files"
##   ..$ From                      : chr "Brian Zhou <brizhou@gmail.com>"
##   ..$ To                        : chr "brianzhou@me.com"
##   ..$ Cc                        : chr "Brian Zhou <brizhou@gmail.com>"
##   ..$ Content-type              : chr "multipart/mixed; boundary=001a113392ecbd7a5404eb6f4d6a"
##   ..$ Authentication-results    : chr "st11p00mm-smtpin007.mac.com; dkim=pass\nreason=\"2048-bit key\" header.d=gmail.com header.i=@gmail.com\nheader."| __truncated__
##   ..$ x-icloud-spam-score       : chr "33322\nf=gmail.com;e=gmail.com;pp=ham;spf=pass;dkim=pass;wl=absent;pwl=absent"
##   ..$ X-Proofpoint-Virus-Version: chr "vendor=fsecure\nengine=2.50.10432:5.10.8794,1.0.14,0.0.0000\ndefinitions=2013-11-18_02:2013-11-18,2013-11-17,19"| __truncated__
##   ..$ X-Proofpoint-Spam-Details : chr "rule=notspam policy=default score=0 spamscore=0\nsuspectscore=0 phishscore=0 bulkscore=0 adultscore=0 classifie"| __truncated__
##  $ sender          :List of 2
##   ..$ sender_email: chr "brizhou@gmail.com"
##   ..$ sender_name : chr "Brian Zhou"
##  $ recipients      :List of 2
##   ..$ :List of 3
##   .. ..$ display_name : NULL
##   .. ..$ address_type : chr "SMTP"
##   .. ..$ email_address: chr "brianzhou@me.com"
##   ..$ :List of 3
##   .. ..$ display_name : NULL
##   .. ..$ address_type : chr "SMTP"
##   .. ..$ email_address: chr "brizhou@gmail.com"
##  $ subject         : chr "Test for TIF files"
##  $ body            : chr "This is a test email to experiment with the MS Outlook MSG Extractor\r\n\r\n\r\n-- \r\n\r\n\r\nKind regards\r\n"| __truncated__
##  $ attachments     :List of 2
##   ..$ :List of 4
##   .. ..$ filename     : chr "importOl.tif"
##   .. ..$ long_filename: chr "import OleFileIO.tif"
##   .. ..$ mime         : chr "image/tiff"
##   .. ..$ content      : raw [1:969674] 49 49 2a 00 ...
##   ..$ :List of 4
##   .. ..$ filename     : chr "raisedva.tif"
##   .. ..$ long_filename: chr "raised value error.tif"
##   .. ..$ mime         : chr "image/tiff"
##   .. ..$ content      : raw [1:1033142] 49 49 2a 00 ...
##  $ display_envelope:List of 2
##   ..$ display_cc: chr "Brian Zhou"
##   ..$ display_to: chr "brianzhou@me.com"
## NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it would be to make use of the excellent Python msg extractor that you can [source from GitHub here](https://github.com/mattgwwalker/msg-extractor). If you feel like being creative you can make use of the `rPython` package to encapsulate that code in `R`.